# Paramiko SSHClient.connect returns False

Tags: python, networking, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to open an SSH connection to the router with Python, after many tries with no outputs whatsoever I figured out that when I print a True/False comparison statement for the `SSHClient.connect` I always get False, I tried many things but nothing worked out!

The Python script I wrote is very common yet the result is not at all (note that I tried accessing different network devices through SSH but yet no connection has been established)

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
success = ssh.connect(hostname="172.16.0.1", username="admin", password="admin")
if (success != True):
    print("not connected")
    sys.exit()
else:
    print("connected")
```

would appreciate any help as I have searched quite a lot and haven't found any similar situation that has been solved!

I'm not getting any errors. I simply am not being able to connect to the remote network device at all through SSH using Python, though I am able to using cmd or PuTTY.

Credentials are 100% correct as I have tried same procedure on different setups after modifying the credentials respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The `SSHClient.connect` does not return anything. It only raises an exception on error. As your call did not raise any exception, the connection was successful.

---

Not returning anything in Python means the method "returns" `None`.

`None != True`, so that's why your code prints *"not connected"*.

Comment: ok all went great my script working just fine now!!

super super super thank you man <3 much love 
have a lovely one